# Jquery on Ctrl paste in clicked input value from input above

Tags: jquery

This is working sample.

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="date_day1" id="date_day1" value=" size="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="date_day2" id="date_day2" value=" size="1">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date_day2").on('click', function(e) {
      var name1 = $('#date_day1').val();
      if(e.ctrlKey) $("#date_day2").val(name1);
    });
  });
  </script>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="date_day3" id="date_day3" value=" size="1"></td>
</tr>
```

I mean if I enter something in date_day1 then press and hold Ctrl and click in date_day2, then value in date_day1 "copy-paste" to date_day2.

To get such behavior for all other input cells I must write the javascript for each input cell.

To use only one javascript for all input cells I try to write code, but it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#input").on('click', function(e) {
    var name1 = $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').find('input').val();
    if(e.ctrlKey) $("#input").val(name1);
  });
});
</script>
```

With $("#input").on('click', function(e) { I mean if I click on any input cell

With var name1 =  .... set/define variable value from closest above input cell

With if(e.ctrlKey) $("#input").val(name1); I mean if press ctrlKey, then current input cell value is name1

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not `#input` but rather `input` and inside the event, you should use `$(this)` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").on('click', function(e) {
      var name1 = $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').find('input').val();

      if(e.ctrlKey) $(this).val(name1);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are using wrong selectors:

```
$('#input')
```

This one stands for element with attribute `id` = `input`. What you need is:

```
$('input')
```

It stands for elements with `tagname` = `input`.
Also, the line with value assignment should be changed, too:

```
$(this).val(name1);
```